# How to have an android like spinner view in iOS?

Tags: ios, uipickerview, android-spinner

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsO9E.png)   My requirement is to show the users all the selection options to the user so that he can see all at once an then able to select from those just like it is done with spinner view in android. Currently I am using UI picker view. I am attaching the screen shot of it. Either I want a spinner or want the picker view to show 10 items simultaneously for the same height where it is currently showing three. This is my code:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
            var myString = view as! UILabel!

            var myStringLength = 0

            if( view == nil) {
                myString = UILabel()
            }
            myString?.textAlignment = .center

            var rowText:String

            if(pickerView==District){
                rowText=districts[row]
            }
            else if(pickerView==block)
            {
                 rowText=blocks[row]
            }
            else if(pickerView==management)
            {
               rowText=managements[row]
            }
            else
            {
                 rowText=categories[row]
            }

            var attributedRowText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: rowText)
            var attributedRowTextLength = attributedRowText.length

            attributedRowText.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.blue, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedRowTextLength))

            attributedRowText.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 8.0)!, range: NSRange(location: 0 ,length:attributedRowTextLength))

            myString!.attributedText = attributedRowText

            return myString!
        }
```

Comment: Vipul if you want data to be like spinner in android so you need to add UITableView. Using that you can show your data in list View.

Comment: Look at the `pickerView(_:rowHeightForComponent:)` delegate method.

Comment: thanks gonna look into it right now

Comment: you can you tableview as dropdown.

Comment: I am very new to iOS hence I am trying to find how to use table view as a dropdown

Comment: Another option: https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use table view as a dropdown:

subCategoryTable is table name. Create this table on press of that dropdown button. here subCatgBtn is that btn on click write this code.

```
    subCategoryTable.frame         =   CGRectMake(self.subCatgBtn.frame.origin.x, self.subCatgBtn.frame.origin.y + self.subCatgBtn.frame.size.height, self.subCatgBtn.frame.size.width,CGFloat(numberofrows * 2));
    subCategoryTable.delegate      =   self
    subCategoryTable.dataSource    =   self
    subCategoryTable.tag = 2
    //subCategoryTable.rowHeight = self.subCatgBtn.frame.size.height
    subCategoryTable.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")//this is needed when you use custom cell otherwise no need
    subCategoryTable.separatorColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    subCategoryTable.allowsSelection   = true
    self.view.addSubview(subCategoryTable)
```

CellforrowIndex:

```
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")!
    if tableView.tag == 2
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell

         //do whatever you want to show.
     }
   }
```

numberofrows method:

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView.tag == 2
    {

     districts.count
    }
    }
```

and on Didselect method just set the name on that button whatever you selected.

I dont know Your UI how you designed, You can use this one as dropdown it will create dynamically when you click on that button.

Comment: I am gonna try this now

Comment: can you email me the example project for this at epunjab.apps@gmail.com

Comment: I given the code from my active project. I can't give you now you try at first If not than I will make one sample project for you and send you.

Comment: I tried to up vote but thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything like spinner in the cocoatouch framework.
At most what you can do is have a custom implementation with UItableView

or you can also use something like [NIDropdown](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/nidropdown) which will help in your implementation.

Comment: I am looking at the dropdown

Comment: NIDropdown is good but it is implemented in objective c. can it be implemented in swift?